# View metadata for song currently playing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, applications, music, metadata

Is there any way to view metadata (such as composer, genre, year etc) for a song that is currently playing on an iPhone?

If there is no way to do so, and no apps which can do this, does the iOS API allow access to this information (i.e. could I write an app to do this myself)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like many apps do this. Look at FlickTunes, for instance, which allows you to use gestures to control playback. Or TuneWiki, which tries to look up the lyrics for the current song. So I assume the API is there and you could write an app that displays this metadata.

Comment: I might try FlickTunes, I can't quite tell if it does what I want but it might be worth it just for the Song Title Scrolling functionality.

Comment: I already have TuneWiki, it doesn't appear to show the song metadata but is great for lyrics.